# How to open my application j hipster without authentication

Tags: java, spring-security, jwt, jhipster, spring-security-oauth2

I have created my j hipster application called Bookstore.After running my application it will go authentication . i need not this authentication .if there is any way to open my application without j hipster log in page?

Answer (score 12):

In the path "app/config" there is the class MicroserviceSecurityConfiguration.class
Change the permissions there, in the case

> ("/api/**").Authenticated()

for

> ("/api/**").permitAll()

Comment: In newer JHipster versions this change should be done in config/SecurityConfiguration.java class generated.
If you only want to open up parts of the api for specific http method, like being able to get a list of entities unauthenticated, look more into antMatchers(httpMethod, path)

Answer (score 1):

To disable Authentication :

- replace  `.antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()`  with  `.antMatchers("/**").permitAll()` in   SecurityConfiguration.java
- Remove from all *.html, all directives of `*jhiHasAnyAuthority` in all `*.html` files
- Remove from all *.html, all directives of  `[ngSwitch]="isAuthenticated()` and all it's `*ngSwitchCase`
- return true in all   `checkLogin(`  methods in all *service.ts files
- see the doc about authorizations.
- i wish it was easier...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to build an application that keeps JHipster admin features:

- Remove `*jhiHasAnyAuthorities` directives on HTML elements you want to make public
- Same thing for *ngSwitch directives dealing with isAuthenticated(), see the [doc about authorizations](https://jhipster.github.io/using-angular/#authorizations).