# Endpoint with no authorization

Tags: jhipster

Is there any possibility of generating an endpoint with jhipster with no authorization? Every endpoint requires authorization header by default (as far as I know), but I would like to allow usage of one of the endpoints without authorization header.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open my application j hipster without authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42393231/how-to-open-my-application-j-hipster-without-authentication)

Comment: This is standard spring security configuration, not specific to JHipster.

Answer (score 1):

You can do do by going to

```
your-app/config/SecurityConfiguration.java
```

on this method

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    ...
    authorizeRequests
```

add this line

```
.antMatchers("/api/some-unsafe-url").permitAll()
```